How to add an anchor to the heading of an accordion item?
I'm editing a detail page that contains an accordion.  I want to add an anchor to the heading of one of the items in the accordion, so that when the user clicks a link with the anchor, the item's heading shows up at the top of the window.  But the closest I can come to that is to put the anchor at the start of the item's text.  This, of course, brings up a screen where the heading is not visible, which defeats the purpose of providing the anchor.  How to place the anchor so that the heading shows up?

What do you mean by "detail page"?

@Demerit By "detail page" I mean what is labeled on the "Manage Contents" form as a "Standard Detail Page".

Still not sure what page you mean... Please provide an example url (remove the domain if you prefer)
